# web service test ejb3 passing as Date parameter

Tags: web-services, testing, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

My web service looks like

```
import entities.Expense;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import logic.ExpenseSessionBeanLocal;

/**
 *
 * @author nikola
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "ExpenseWebService")
@Stateless()
public class ExpenseWebService {
    @EJB
    private ExpenseSessionBeanLocal ejbRef;// Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Web Service Operation")

    @WebMethod(operationName = "makeExpenseOnce")
    public Expense makeExpenseOnce(@WebParam(name = "expenseName") String expenseName, @WebParam(name = "expenseRecipient") String expenseRecipient, @WebParam(name = "purpose") String purpose, @WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "expenseDate") Date expenseDate, @WebParam(name = "amount") BigDecimal amount, @WebParam(name = "currency") String currency) {
        return ejbRef.makeExpenseOnce(expenseName, expenseRecipient, purpose, username, expenseDate, amount, currency);
    }

}
```

Image from test is below

[image]

How to input date in the test with javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to pass Objects to the Webservice-Tester (other than Strings). At least I never managed to post BigIntegers, for instance.